# Expected variable-declaration to have a typedef

Tags: typescript, eslint, tslint

I have this code showing a warning:

`const linkElement = getByText(/learn react/i);`

> expected variable-declaration: 'linkElement' to have a typedef (typedef)tslint(1)

`getByText` is typed to: `(text: Matcher, options?: SelectorMatcherOptions | undefined, waitForElementOptions?: unknown) => HTMLElement`

Why do I explicitly need to declare a typedef given TS knows `linkElement` is an `HTMLElement`?

I have added the following to my `.eslintrc` but the warning persists:

```
"plugins": [
    "jsx-a11y",
    "prefer-arrow",
    "@typescript-eslint/tslint"
  ],
...
"rules": {
  "@typescript-eslint/typedef": [
      "off",
      {
        "variableDeclaration": false
      }
    ],
  "@typescript-eslint/no-inferrable-types": "error",
```

Comment: Are you sure it comes from eslint? Looks like tslist according to warning message

Comment: @AlekseyL. I admit I'm a little out of my depth here... I had to add an eslint plugin
for tslint, presumably because it doesn't yet cover all of tslint's rules?
I had to explicitly add tslint as a dependency of my project, which seemed
a little weird, but otherwise I get `Error: Failed to load plugin '@typescript-eslint/tslint' declared in '.eslintrc': Cannot find module 'tslint'`. I've updated my question to include the tslint plugin in my config.

Comment: I didn't now this option even exist (and sounds a bit weird ) Anyway I wouldn't go this path as tslint is already deprecated and even typescript itself uses eslint

Comment: @AlekseyL.I think I'll take your advice, there are couple rules I can't find analogs for (yet), but I don't thihk it's worth wrestling with this.